# How to configure Javadocs for Android in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse

I found here already a few posts for this problem but also with this help I dont get it running on my machine.

I want to attach the android source code to the android.jar. I tried a few ways but somehow it does not show any android source code. Here is my folder structure where my android sdk is

[Image here http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/111OkUca.png](http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/111OkUca.png)

Even if I attach the folder of the requested android-16 plattform it wont show the source.

[image here http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/1125INcC.png](http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/1125INcC.png)

What is my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Java 7 javadoc from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html

if you have the "Documentation for Android" package and the javadoc info still isn't showing up, make sure the Android library settings point to the right folder:

Project -> Settings -> Java Build Path, Libraries tab

Android X.X -> Android.jar -> Javadoc Location:
Should be something like "sdk_root/docs/reference/".

And to view the docs for a class in editor for example:

you should choose show attached java doc in web browser from to popup that appear when hover the cursor on some declaration.

Comment: I dont know what I am making wrong. I cannot attach the sources of android to the android.jar.

Comment: hey but do u try that which like i have posted.

Comment: for sure I tried the steps you described, but it wont work on my side.